# VS Code start gdbserver

Tags: visual-studio-code, gdbserver

I am trying to write a launch configuration for VS Code that can start `gdbserver` as a preLaunchTask.

When I start debugging, everything just stalls when gdbserver says "Listening on port XXXX"

I found many examples online of methods for other debuggers, but nothing specific for gdbserver.

I have tried setting `isBackground` to `true` to no avail, along with trying to set up a `problemMatcher`

I couldn't find any documentation that seemed to explain how to write your own `problemMatcher` either.

So, how do I write a task that can start gdbserver as part of a preLaunchTask for my debugger?

Here is my task to start gdbserver

```
{
    "label": "run",
    "type": "shell",
    "presentation": {
        "echo": true,
        "reveal": "always",
        "focus": false,
        "panel": "dedicated"
        },
    "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/build"
    },
    "command": "ssh",
    "args": [
            "root@remote",
            "'gdbserver localhost:9091 program'"
    ]     
}
```

Here is my launch configuration

```
{
    "name": "Remote Debug",
    "type": "cppdbg",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/build/program",
    "args": [],
    "stopAtEntry": false,
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "environment": [],
    "externalConsole": true,
    "MIMode": "gdb",
    "setupCommands": [
        {
            "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
            "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
            "ignoreFailures": true
        }
    ],
    "preLaunchTask": "run",
    "miDebuggerServerAddress": "remote:9091",
    "miDebuggerPath": "aarch64-sbs-linux-gdb"
}
]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issues as you. I got it running using a pattern matcher and running it in the background.
The task only starts the gdbserver on the remote target. It doesn't compiles or send the files to the remote target.

```
{
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "Start gdbserver",
        "command": "ssh",
        "args": [
            "root@remote",
            "gdbserver localhost:3000 ${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        // "dependsOn": [
        //     "optional build task"
        // ],
        "presentation": {
            "echo": true,
            "reveal": "always",
            "focus": false,
            "panel": "shared",
            "showReuseMessage": true,
            "clear": false
        },
        "group": "build",
        "detail": "Starts the gdbserver and waits for success",
        "isBackground": true,
        "problemMatcher": {
            "pattern": [
                {
                    "regexp": ".",
                    "file": 1,
                    "location": 2,
                    "message": 3
                }
            ],
            "background": {
                "activeOnStart": true,
                "beginsPattern": "^.*Process*",
                "endsPattern": "^.*Listening*"
            }
        }
    },
```